# Sass instead of Stylus in VueJs Hackernews 2.0

Tags: vue.js

I've cloned and installed this VueJs SSR application (created by Vuejs community itself):

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-hackernews-2.0

I want to change the CSS preprocessor from stylus to Sass, so what i did is:

Install sass dependencies:

```
npm install -D sass-loader node-sass
```

Add rule to webpack config (`build/webpack.base.config.js`):

```
rules: [
      // ... other rules omitted

      // this will apply to both plain `.scss` files
      // AND `<style lang="scss">` blocks in `.vue` files
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader'
        ]
      }
    ]
```

when i run `npm run dev` i got this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                       5:54:17 PM

 error  in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&lang=scss&

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (13:5)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| 
| body {
|   background: #000
| }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your vue-loader config seems perfect according to [official documentation](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/pre-processors.html#sass).
However in your CSS you're missing a semicolon
you have to change this:

```
body {
  background: #000
}
```

to this one:

```
body {
  background: #000;
}
```